# How do I start PowerShell from an environment variable?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I can start cmd.exe using the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable, what is the equivalent for PowerShell?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's an application that uses %COMSPEC% to launch a command prompt, was just curious if there was another variable that could do the same thing only with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no default environment variable like `%COMSPEC%` in Windows, only `%PSModulePath%` the location of modules used by PowerShell.

You can, for example, change `%COMSPEC%` to start Powershell or set up a new environment variable yourself. Whatever makes more sense for your actual context/goal (which I recommend you should state in your question in order to get better and more specific answers).

Run `gci env:* | sort-object name` in PS to get the environment variables but note, that there are also variables like `%CMDCMDLINE%`, the command line used to launch an existing CMD session.